# How can I get the first and last paragraph of each section of a document?

Tags: string, algorithm, haskell

I am having trouble in constructing the algorithm for the following problem: given a textbook ([this one](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/6052?msg=welcome_stranger)), find every first and last paragraph of every section.

Getting every paragraph is easy in Haskell using `split`, `groupify` or `filter` by passing the newline parameter and that works fine. However, the rest is complicated for me (I'm only familiar with OOP). If we take the titles as the base case, there will be two title strings in the text: one in the index part, and one in the text itself. How can the program distinguish between them? Furthermore, how can the code know whether there are two empty lines between two paragraphs?

This is my attempt to solve the problem;

1. Get every paragraph into an array by splitting the text into elements of paragraph
2. Search the index of the titles in the array and find the second occurence of each title and name that index
3. Get paragraph_array[index+1] as the first element
4. Get paragraph_array[index-1] as the last element of previous section.

I am very confused. Any help would be very appreciated.

UPDATE: A section is something like a part of every title. For example a calculus book may contain 12 chapter and each chapter may have 8 sections. We need to think for that book it has only one chapter and it has 4-5 sections. 
A title can be INTEGRAL, LIMIT, etc.

Comment: `there will be 2 title string in the text` In this particular text, title strings in the text itself always come right after newlines. In the index they are preceded by spaces.

Comment: What's a section? Looks like a key part of the question, and probably the first thing to split by, yet you hardly even mention it in your question.

Comment: it would be more clear if you put some little examples among your algorithm, especially paragraphs, titles, sections.

Comment: I added the updates to the question. Thanks for warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sketch for how I would approach this problem.

I assume you have some function `isTitle :: String -> Bool` that can
determine if a certain string is a title and that you have your text
split into a list of paragraphs and titles (i.e. of type `[String]`).

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
module FindParagraphs where

import Data.Maybe
```

I start with a datatype with a cursor of two elements into a list,
such a datatype is often called a Zipper.

```
data TwoZip a =
  TwoZip { front :: [a]
         , first :: a
         , second :: a
         , back :: [a]
         }
  deriving (Eq, Show)

-- make a zipper from a list
mkZip :: [a] -> Maybe (TwoZip a)
mkZip (first:second:back) = Just (TwoZip [] first second back)
mkZip _ = Nothing

-- advance the zipper
advance :: TwoZip a -> Maybe (TwoZip a)
advance TwoZip{..}
  | (x:xs) <- back = Just (TwoZip (first:front) second x xs)
advance _ = Nothing

-- and rewind our zipper (not needed in this case but nice for
-- completeness sake)
rewind :: TwoZip a -> Maybe (TwoZip a)
rewind TwoZip{..}
  | (x:xs) <- front = Just (TwoZip xs x first (second:back))
rewind _ = Nothing
```

To find all first paragraphs we iterate over the paragraphs and look
at the first element in our zipper, if it is a title we know that the
next element in the zipper is a first paragraph, then we advance!

```
findFirsts
  :: (String -> Bool) -- ^ is collection of words a title
  -> [String] -- ^ Titles and paragraphs
  -> [String] -- ^ last and first paragraphs
findFirsts isTitle paragraphs = reverse (go (fromJust (mkZip paragraphs)) [])
  where
    go
      :: TwoZip String
      -> [String]
      -> [String]
    go z@TwoZip{..} firsts =
      let
        firsts' =
          if isTitle first
          then second:firsts
          else firsts
      in case advance z of
        Nothing -> firsts'
        Just z' -> go z' firsts'
```

And then some (simplified) test data:

```
testData = map show [1,2,3,1,3,4,1,4,3]
isTitle = (== "1")

first_paragraphs = findFirsts isTitle testData
```

And as we would want:

```
λ> first_paragraphs
["2","3","4"]
```

You can probably figure out how to extend this to also finding the
last paragraph and how to do them in one iteration.

Comment: I don't think this is the right solution for my problem :/

Comment: Please do elaborate on why!

Comment: First of all, i don't think this does not solve the problem for not having any empty lines between the title and the paragraph, and your test case is an array of integers and i couldn't solve how to test with my file. And the code is so complicated and advance for me which i don't want it to be because i am very new to haskell and looking for a more basic and understandable solution.

Comment: @user3104760: were you able to use any of the above?

Comment: Yep sorry for misunderstanding of mine i was just learning brand new. Thanks for helping :)